# Eclipse Web Indent to new line

Tags: html, eclipse, eclipse-wtp

Trying to get indentation correct in html files.

Following this SO answer but hasn't resolved https://stackoverflow.com/a/18365664/461887

What I am getting

```
<div class="why"></div>
```

when I press enter

```
<div class="why">
</div>
```

what I want is

```
<div class="why">
    |
</div>
```

Comment: did u ever solve this?